# Call javascript functions from each page

Tags: plugins, functions, customization, jquery, javascript

Is there a plugin that supports calling custom functions that you've created?

Like,

page A -- I want to call function x

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    call_function_x()
});
```

page B -- I want to call function y

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    call_function_y()
});
```

I don't want to write the calls in the main input because of others editing and might delete them by misstake...

This is my current solution but not optimal in my eyes :)

```
footer.php:

    <?php
        /* Always have wp_footer() just before the closing </body>
         * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
         * generally use this hook to reference JavaScript files.
         */

        wp_footer();
        $js =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'javascript', true);
            if ( $js != "" ) {
    ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    <?php echo $js; ?>
});
<?php } ?>
```

then I added custom field "javascript" on the pages with their custom functions like this.

```
function_x(some_variable); function_y(some_var); function_foo(bar);
```

Comment: Do you want to avoid using custom fields as well?

Comment: @kidakaka yes I would like to but... maybe that's to much to ask for though...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a custom field containing the function to be called, for example called 'function_to_call'.
In the templatefile add the code

```
$function_to_call = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'function_to_call', true );
if ( $function_to_call != "" ) {
    echo '
          jQuery(document).ready(function($){
              ' . $function_to_call . '()
          });
    ';
}
```

Doing this only outputs the function if you set one in the Custom Fields. You could also make a list of available Functions to avoid Javascript errors.

Comment: @fish, yeah I did a solution like that but I don't really like it, see my edit.

Comment: but maybe that's the easiest and most effective solution ...

Comment: you have to store the values somewhere - so the custom field is your best option. maybe you could create a custom metabox not visible for the editors, containing all the usable functions.

Comment: Yeah, as you say, I need to store them somewhere and I think custom fields will do it for now. Thanks!